# How to return the smallest distance to a point?

Tags: lambda, prolog

I'm trying to solve a problem where i have a list of coordinates and want to get the closest to a point.

Example: 
I got the coordinates [[1,2],[3,4],[10,3]] and want to get the closest point to the origin [0,0]. [1,2] in this example.

I wrote this:

```
list_min([H|T], Min):-
   list_min(T, H, Min).

list_min([], H, H).

list_min([L|Ls], Min0, Min) :-
    point(P),
    distance(Min0,P,D0),
    distance(L,P,D1),
    Lower is min(D0, D1),
    assert(candidate(Min0)),
    assert(candidate(L)),
    forall(candidate(X),distance(X,P,Lower)),
    retractall(candidate(_)),
    list_min(Ls, X, Min).

distance(A,B,D):-
    A = [A1,A2],
    B = [B1,B2],
    Y is B2 - A2,
    X is B1 - A1,
    D is sqrt(X*X + Y*Y).
```

However, looks like it always fail in forall line. What i'm doing wrong? Is there a better way for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a solution without the suggested library or the quadtree, I stay in basic prolog (I write in SWI).

There is actually no need for `assert`/`retract`/`forall` if I understand your problem correctly. I assume that `point(P)` says that P is the uniquely-defined reference point from which we calculate distances, but it is a bit weird (I would use it as a parameter, to ensure it is unique).

```
point([0,0]). % The reference point

% Entry point predicate
% First parameter : a list of points
% Second parameter (result) : the point closest to the reference point
list_min([H|Tail], Min) :-
  point(Reference),
  distance(H, Reference, D),
  list_min(Tail, H, D, Min).

% First parameter : the list remaining to consider
% Second parameter : the closest point, at this point of the computation
% Third parameter : the corresponding (minimum) distance, at this point of the computation
% Fourth parameter : the result (one point, to be bound at the end of computation)
list_min([], CurrentMin, _, CurrentMin). % Stop condition : list processed
list_min([Candidate|Tail], CurrentMin, CurrentDist, Min) :-
  point(Reference),
  distance(Candidate, Reference, CandidateDist),
  (
   % if the new candidate is not better, keep the current candidate
   CurrentDist < CandidateDist ->
   list_min(Tail, CurrentMin, CurrentDist, Min)
  ;
   % if the new candidate is better, take it as the current candidate
   list_min(Tail, Candidate, CandidateDist, Min) 
   ).

distance(A,B,D):- % copy-pasted from your version
  A = [A1,A2],
  B = [B1,B2],
  Y is B2 - A2,
  X is B1 - A1,
  D is sqrt(X*X + Y*Y).
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)):

```
distance_min(L, MinXY) :-
    distance_min(L, 0, 0, MinXY).
distance_min(L, X0, Y0, MinXY) :-
    aggregate(min(D, [X,Y]),
              (member([X,Y], L), D is sqrt((X-X0)^2+(Y-Y0)^2)),
              MinXY).
```

test:

```
?- distance_min([[1,2],[3,4],[10,3]], R).
R = min(2.23606797749979, [1, 2]).
```

**edit**

```
....
assert(candidate(Min0)),
assert(candidate(L)),
forall(candidate(X),distance(X,P,Lower)),
retractall(candidate(_)),
...
```

I didn't commented your code, but here now a hint: these lines are really in bad style, and really useless. Admitting forall/2 succeds, what outcome do you expect?

Anyway, forall/2 fails because `Lower` it's already instanced from a statement above (`Lower is min(D0, D1)`), thus distance/3 will fail where `D` don't match.

Answer (score 2):

With SWI-Prolog, You can also use a functionnal style :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).


point([0,0]). % The reference point

% Entry point predicate
% First parameter : a list of points
% Second parameter (result) : the point closest to the reference point
list_min([H|Tail], Min) :-
  point(Reference),
  distance(H, Reference, D),

  foldl(\X^Y^Z^(distance(X, Reference, DX),
                Y = [Cur_D, _Cur_P],
                (   DX < Cur_D
                ->  Z = [DX, X]
                ;   Z = Y)),
    Tail, [D, H], Min).


distance(A,B,D):- % copy-pasted from your version
  A = [A1,A2],
  B = [B1,B2],
  Y is B2 - A2,
  X is B1 - A1,
  D is sqrt(X*X + Y*Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a quad-tree for 2D http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: Really a weird answer: quadtrees are useful in some context, but really useless here. Did you mean [K-D-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) with K=2?